# Can I use IS42SM16160K DRAM instead of IS42S16400 DRAM?

Tags: dram

I have designed a custom board based on the STM32F4 controller and IS42S16400 DRAM. For some reason, I want to use IS42SM16160K mobile DRAM instead.

Should there be a change in programming and software packages?

Answer (score 0):

*"For some reason "* — don't you know why you want to make this change?

In any case, no — the chips are in very different packages, and a board designed for one will not work with the other, unless you had the foresight to use a dual footprint.

Furthermore, the chips are very different sizes, so there will be changes required in the configuration of the memory controller as well.

Comment: Both chips are the same footprint. this is my question: Can I use the same BSP for both designs?

Comment: You said that you designed the board, so the BSP is entirely on you. To what extent is your board compatible with any existing BSP? To what extent can your BSP accommodate different memory configurations? There's no way we can answer these questions for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.